# Symfony: after login and all other pages redirect

Tags: php, symfony

after login, i want the user redirect to a page like polling, so he/she can't do or go to other menu if he/she doesn't done that polling.
That polling is come from database which depends on the time range.
If i put every controller to check if user has done polling or not and redirect to a page, doesn't it not efficient?
And if i put it after login controller, user can click menu or point to other routing to pass that polling.

Comment: what i mean is i want my website redirect user to one page and he need to submit that form to do any other thing, while i have menu which he can just click to go away if i put it in action after login.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler solution would be to redirect the user to a specific action after the successfull login. This actions will return the user to the main page or the polling page depending on whatever condition you prefer to set. So this this action can be treated as an entry point of the user in the system. Next, Using kernel.controller event dispatcher, check this action for every request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `kernel.controller` listener to check some condition on every request. It will be the right way. You will only need to define it in one place.

You can read about this approach at official docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html